# Is there a way that you can get a Portable/Online  Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, ide

I am just starting out with the Arduino, and I want to develop and create sketches at my school.  The only problem is that the school's computer doesn't allow any application to run if app tries to create a folder on its hard-drive.  Are there any ways to make the standard  IDE portable, or is there another portable option?

Comment: Can you tell the IDE where to put folders?  Maybe throw it on an external drive or some other storage, run it from there, and tell it to create all the directories on that drive.

Comment: the biggest challenge for something like this would be supporting the myriad libraries out there... I'm actually working on a project that has this capability as one of its goals... http://www.sketchgarden.co but it won't be ready for at least a couple of months.

Comment: @vicatcu Well, I have some knowledge of Java, so if you want some external input, I am open to help!

Comment: @KrisBahnsen I can try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard IDE *is* portable as it runs as a stand-alone Java application. As such it requires no "installation" so to speak, and projects exist. So if you have it on rewritable media (e.g. a USB flash drive) and you store your projects on that same media, you in effect have a portable IDE. It will (I'm pretty sure) however, keep all it's build artifacts in temporary folders under the current users HOME directory.

Comment: But, that being said, the computer says that the IDE is trying to create a folder on the hard-drive, which doesn't work in my school.  +1 anyways (if and when I have 15 rep), but not exactly what the question asked.

Comment: When in the process is this occurring?  When you try to compile a sketch?

Comment: I believe that the IDE tries to create the SketchBook folder somewhere in the system, which my school's admins don't like  :(

Comment: The Arduino IDE's SketchBook folder location is configurable in the IDE preferences.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of projects working on online IDEs for Arduino. My project, called wifino, is probably the most developed at this point. You can try out the beta at http://ide.wifino.com. Code still needs to be moved to the Arduino using avrdude, but we're working on a deployment client for windows, mac/linux, and (drum roll) iPhone using 802.11b/g networks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into issues with this while teaching arduino to one of my classes.  Without admin access, you can't install the device driver for the arduino and with Windows 7 the JVM is not installed by default.

I built live debian DVDs that have the IDE installed and just have them boot the cds to work with the arduinos.  Should work fine until campus IT gets wise and blocks booting from CD/DVDs

Answer (score 1):

To go portable you can use a portable [Chrome Browser](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) and install the extension to the site below.

-->[codebender](http://codebender.cc/)<--

Once the extension is install you can connect your Arduino and start building.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that @vicatcu has the complete answer to the question. In reference to Processing 2.0 to 2.2, not only the sketchbook location, but also the preferences file itself, modes and other folders are placed on the hard drive. But with a few quick modifications to a file that strongly urges against modification, we can achieve portable Processing.

As @vicatcu mentioned, the sketchbook folder location can be set in the IDE via File>Preferences>Sketchbook location. But I'd suggest not to do that; simply set that path with the defaults.txt file. Additionally, the settings path must be set.

These sketchbook and settings paths can be modified in "lib/defaults.txt" by uncommenting lines #sketchbook.path= and #settings.path=. You can use local paths such as "sketchbook.path=sketchbook" which will put these folders into the Processing IDE folder. The folders will then be created when you start up Processing. Note that when relative directories are used, the Processing folder must be user-writeable, so don't put it into "C:/Program Files". Also, Processing should not be running until after you make the changes to the defaults.txt file.

Comment: I did attempt to get this made more transparent but the product maintainers don't want to modify it. Maybe in Processing 3.0 it will be easier.